# Can an application access another applications back stack?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know some basics about the structure of Android components. Does an application have access to the data of another applications back stack?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

You could have two applications with a [sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid). They must be signed with the same  developer certificate. Then you could share access to the back stack. But the application whose back stack you wish to access has to provide that access via and exposed interface. I think it is not a good idea to try this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to know for the security purpose. If the application in back stack can access information of another application.